# Pigeonhole Principle proof question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, contest-math

For the problem below, I'm wondering if we could've proved it by considering that there must exist the same remainder for $2$ different terms instead of sums.  There are $n$ terms, each are subsets, and if none are divisible by $n$ then there must exist $2$ terms with the same remainder mod$n$.  Then just subtract them mod $n$ would give a difference with remainder $0$ mod $n$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why does it say that all the remainders of $s_k$ are different modulo $n$? Rather, $s_k$ are all nonzero modulo $n$, and there are only $n-1$ nonzero remainders modulo $n$, so there exists two of them with equal remainder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the existence of two terms with the same residue modulo $n$. The only flaw in your approach is that unlike $s_k-s_l$, the term $a_k-a_l$ is not necessarily a sum of some subset of $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$.

Comment: I figured I'd run into problems with negating one of the terms.  Thanks!